# Eevee render with blurred textures when not facing the camera

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, blur

I run into a problem while doing something in eevee and texture painting.

I noticed that a texture is not rendered properly when not facing directly to the camera. It is blurred and low res.

As you can see, the steps are blurred and ugly.
[image]

when facing the camera, it is all good
[image]

Is there a way to make step's texture looking good even if it is not facing the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is cause by low or lack of anisotropic filter. You could try increase the filtering through Blender Preferences located in:

**Edit>Preferences**

Then in **Viewport** tab, Under **Textures** you'll see **Anisotropic Filter**

---

[image]
Image example above: **Anisotropic Filter - Off**

---

[image]
Image example above: **Anisotropic Filter - 16x**

Comment: will work on both viewport and render?

Comment: I think it should affect final render. If not then maybe you can try increase Eevee's render sample beyond 128, maybe 256 etc.

Comment: helped a bit, but not much, still best option.